# Django embed video не работает с HTTPS

Tags: django, видео, youtube, embedded

После переноса сайта на Django на VPS перестали отображаться видео, добавленные через django-embed-video из-за смены протокола на HTTPS.

Пробовал делать, как сказано в [инструкции](https://django-embed-video.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#template-examples) по этому поводу, но ничего хорошего не получается:

```
<div class="row">

   {% for my_video in addvideo_list %}

        <div class="video">

            {% video my_video query="rel=0&wmode=transparent" is_secure=True as my_video %}
            {{ my_video.url }}  # Получаем строку https://www.youtube.com/embed/8e7kiXsLvbg?rel=0&wmode=transparent
            {% video my_video 'small' %}  # Все равно нет HTTPS <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/1cCLguVQsMU?wmode=opaque" loading="lazy" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> 
            {% endvideo %}

        </div>

   {% endfor %}

</div>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

views

```
class AddVideoListView(ListView):
     request.scheme = 'https'
     model = AddVideo
     queryset = AddVideo.objects.exclude(published=False).order_by('?')
     paginate_by = 21
```

Comment: т.е у вас урл хранится с https а выводится без?

Comment: там урл перепарсивается

Comment: Да с HTTPS. Вот мне и надо, чтобы он не переписывался.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже is_secure как параметр теперь не используется.

Вместо этого переменная тащится отсюда `HttpRequest.is_secure()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_secure

Для деплоя на нгинкс [добавьте](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19637196/2101808)

```
location / {
    # ... 
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

Как костыль можно во вьюхе воткнуть

```
request.scheme = 'https'
```

Comment: django-embed-video==1.4.0

Comment: Из-за is_secure изменения есть, но только в {{ my_video.url }}, где мы получаем только строку.

Comment: @ArgumentSite переписал ответ. проверь понимает ли джанга что она за хттпс

Comment: В админке, кстати, видео нормально отображается.

Comment: request.scheme во вьюхе что показывает?

Comment: Я, наверное, не то делаю, но выдает ошибку: name 'request' is not defined. (вьюху добавил в вопрос)

Comment: @ArgumentSite в классовых нет такого свойства)

Comment: @ArgumentSite x forwarded proto пробовал добавить?